# Dictionary only printing from 2nd keys&values onwards?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to attempt a python question regarding queue.

I am wondering why the dictionary is only printing values from the 2nd key and value pair. Why is the first pair not being printed?

Here are the relevant codes:

```
n = int(input("Enter total number of people queueing."))
dict = {}

for i in range(n):
    inputKey = input("Select your choice of queue. Please enter 'M' for main queue or 'T' for team queue.\n")
    inputValue = input("Enter your name: ")
    dict[inputKey] = inputValue

print(dict)
```

**Sample Input:**

```
3
M
Bella
M
Swan
T
Cullen
```

**Actual Output:**

```
{'M': 'Swan', 'T': 'Cullen'}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
{'M': 'Bella', 'M': 'Swan', 'T': 'Cullen'}
```

Comment: because you overwrite the first value when you enter the same key for the second value

Comment: As side note: it is better to not use `dict` as variable name in python, as it shadow built-in `dict`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Sayse explains, you are overwriting the values.

If you would like to append new entries you could use the following:

```py
n = int(input("Enter total number of people queueing."))
dictionary = {}

for i in range(n):
    inputKey = input("Select your choice of queue. Please enter 'M' for main queue or 'T' for team queue.\n")
    inputValue = input("Enter your name: ")
    if inputKey in dictionary:
        dictionary[inputKey].append(inputValue)
    else:
        dictionary[inputKey] = [inputValue]

print(dictionary)
```

It would return the following output:

`{'M': ['Bella', 'Swan'], 'T': ['Cullen']}`

I would also avoid naming dictionaries `dict`.

As keys need to be unique in a `dict`, your expected output of `{'M': 'Bella', 'M': 'Swan', 'T': 'Cullen'}` is not possible.

If you were a `dict` and someone asked you to return the value for the key `M`, what value would you return, `Bella` or `Swan`?